# Quantmod R , how to select cells with Sys.date?

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm making some calculations based on quantmod for some stocks.

Below I prepared a very  simple example to reflect what I'd like to do which is at this time select some cells based on date, for example yesterday.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("BAC", from="2018-06-18", src="yahoo")
```

As a result I get the following:

[image: Quantmod Result]
Now I'd like to make some calculations with the volume of yesterday so I wonder if something like this could work:

```
# I would like to multiply yesterday's volume for 1.05.
Vol_k <- (BAC$BAC.Volume Sys.Date()-1) * 1.05
```

How do I use sys.date here to indicate **today -1** and select the volume cell of yesterday date?

Thank you very much for any comment.

V.

Comment: `quantmod` is returning an `xts` time series object.  The help page for `xts` has a good description of how to specify dates for this type of time series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I pulled this data, I don't get anything for yesterday being the 4th July (timezone I assume, or maybe due to public holiday in US?) so I did it for 2 days ago.

```
BAC[Sys.Date() - 2, "BAC.Volume"]
```

should give you the desired result of the volume. Did a bit of research (https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/blog_assets/xts_Cheat_Sheet_R.pdf)

```
last(BAC, '1 day')$BAC.Volume
```

should give you the last day, regardless of weekends/ holidays

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the last value by accessing the index.i.e.

```
xts.object[max(index(xts.object),column]
```

In your case:

```
BAC[max(index(BAC)),"BAC.Volume"]
```